# How to find an index for a substring?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How would i find an index of a sub string within a string without using the find method and the index method? Do i need to loop or use the len method?

```
def substring_test(x,y):
  if y in x:
       r = True
  else:
       r = False
  return r

t = input("Enter a string: ")
v = input("Enter a starting substring ")
result = substring_test(sentence, substring)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use `find` and `index` method then you need to brute-force it.

1. Start from position 0
2. get the characters till the length of the string being searched from position
3. If the string matches, return position
4. otherwise, increment position
5. if position is greater than or equal to the difference between the actual string and the searched string return -1
6. Otherwise go to 2

You can implement this algorithm, like this

```
def substring_test(x, y):
    if len(y) > len(x):
        return -1
    for i in range(len(x) - len(y) + 1):
        if x[i:i+len(y)] == y:
            return i
    return -1
```

Comment: Oh ok , thanks for explaining it, i never understood how it was possible now i understad

Comment: When i run through it, keeps returning -1 no matter what

Comment: @Bob Ah, there was a minor typo which prevented it from working fine. I fixed it now. Please check the answer now.